# Using streams to collect into TreeSet with custom comparator

Tags: java, collections, java-8

Working in Java 8, I have a `TreeSet` defined like this:

```
private TreeSet<PositionReport> positionReports = 
        new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(PositionReport::getTimestamp));
```

`PositionReport` is a rather simple class defined like this:

```
public static final class PositionReport implements Cloneable {
    private final long timestamp;
    private final Position position;

    public static PositionReport create(long timestamp, Position position) {
        return new PositionReport(timestamp, position);
    }

    private PositionReport(long timestamp, Position position) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Now I want to remove entries from the `TreeSet positionReports` where `timestamp` is older than some value. But I cannot figure out the correct Java 8 syntax to express this.

This attempt actually compiles, but gives me a new `TreeSet` with an undefined comparator:

```
positionReports = positionReports
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.timestamp >= oldestKept)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))
```

How do I express, that I want to collect into a `TreeSet` with a comparator like `Comparator.comparingLong(PositionReport::getTimestamp)` ?

I would have thought something like

```
positionReports = positionReports
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.timestamp >= oldestKept)
        .collect(
            Collectors.toCollection(
                TreeSet::TreeSet(Comparator.comparingLong(PositionReport::getTimestamp))
            )
        );
```

But this does not compile / appear to be valid syntax for method references.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Method references can be used when you have a method (or constructor) that fits the shape of the target you're trying to satisfy. You can't use a method reference in this case because the shape you're targeting is a `Supplier`, which takes no arguments, but what you have is a `TreeSet` constructor, which does take an argument, and you need to specify what that argument is. So you have to take the less concise approach and use a lambda expression:

```
TreeSet<Report> toTreeSet(Collection<Report> reports, long timestamp) {
    return reports.stream().filter(report -> report.timestamp() >= timestamp).collect(
        Collectors.toCollection(
            () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Report::timestamp))
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that you do not need the comparator if the type of your TreeSet  (in this case PositionReport) implements comparable.

Comment: Following up on @xtrakBandit — again if you don't need to specify the comparator (natural sorting) — you can make it very concise: `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));`

Comment: I got this error: `toCollection in class Collectors cannot be applied to given types`

Comment: @BahadirTasdemir The code works. Make sure you're only passing one argument to `Collectors::toCollection`: a `Supplier` that returns a `Collection`. `Supplier` is a type with just a single abstract method, which means it can be the target of a lambda expression as in this answer. The lambda expression must take no arguments (hence the empty argument list `()`) and return a collection with an element type that matches the type of the elements in the stream you're collecting (in this case a `TreeSet<PositionReport>`).

Answer (score 16):

This is easy just use next code:

```
    positionReports = positionReports
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.timestamp >= oldestKept)
        .collect(
            Collectors.toCollection(()->new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(PositionReport::getTimestamp)
)));
```

Answer (score 10):

You can just convert into a SortedSet at the end (provided that you don't mind the additional copy).

```
positionReports = positionReports
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getTimeStamp() >= oldestKept)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

return new TreeSet(positionReports);
```

Comment: You must careful while doing this. You MIGHT lose elements while doing this.

Like in the question asked above, the natural comparator of the elements is different than the one OP wants to use. So you in the initial conversion, since it is a set, it might lose some elements which the other comparator might have not (i.e the first comparator might return `compareTo()`  as 0 while the other might have not for some comparisions. All the ones where `compareTo()` is 0 is lost as this is a set. )

Answer (score 6):

There is a method on Collection for this without having to use streams: `default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`.  See [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

So your code could just look like this:

```
positionReports.removeIf(p -> p.timestamp < oldestKept);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with TreeSet is that the comparator that we want for sorting the items is used also for detecting duplicates when inserting items into the set. So if the comparator function is 0 for two items it wrongly discards one considering it as duplicate.

The duplicates detection should be done by a separate correct hashCode method of the items. I prefer to use a simple HashSet to prevent duplicates with a hashCode considering all properties (id and name in the example) and return a simple sorted List when getting the items (sorting only by name in the example):

```
public class ProductAvailableFiltersDTO {

    private Set<FilterItem> category_ids = new HashSet<>();

    public List<FilterItem> getCategory_ids() {
        return category_ids.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FilterItem::getName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void setCategory_ids(List<FilterItem> category_ids) {
        this.category_ids.clear();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(category_ids)) {
            this.category_ids.addAll(category_ids);
        }
    }
}


public class FilterItem {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public FilterItem(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof FilterItem)) return false;
        FilterItem that = (FilterItem) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getName(), that.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getId(), getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
positionReports = positionReports.stream()
                             .filter(p -> p.getTimeStamp() >= oldestKept)
                             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new 
TreeSet<PositionReport>(Comparator.comparingLong(PositionReport::getTimestamp))));
```